# Temp table column type error when values are null

Tags: postgresql

I am using a temp table to hold some data while I tidy up a database table. Narrowed down, it goes something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE fw_temp AS SELECT time, version, device_id FROM fw_status;
DELETE FROM fw_status;
INSERT INTO fw_status SELECT * FROM fw_temp
```

On my INSERT statement I get some.. interesting behaviour when the values in the device_id column are null:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "device_id" is of type bigint but expression is of type text
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

As the error message may lead on, device_id is indeed bigint type in the table, but appears to have lost the type when we select from the temp table.

Making a general select,

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE fw_temp AS SELECT * FROM fw_status;
DELETE FROM fw_status;
INSERT INTO fw_status SELECT * FROM fw_temp
```

interestingly does not cause this error.

Now, the real temp table is a bit more complex, so sadly going with SELECT * is not an option. How can I go about this error?

Comment: Maybe `INSERT INTO fw_status (time, version, device_id) SELECT * FROM fw_temp;`. Misplaced and missing column values?

Comment: Funny thing, I figured the same and saw your comment while posting the fix.
Any idea what happens behind the scene? I notice column order does not appear to be maintained on the general select

Comment: You were trying to insert into the wrong columns of `fw_status` - the first three - regardless of what column names  the select statement is producing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE fw_temp AS SELECT time, version, device_id FROM fw_status;
DELETE FROM fw_status;
INSERT INTO fw_status (time, version, device_id) SELECT time, version, device_id FROM fw_temp
```

resolved the issue. Apparently, you can mix general select and general insert or specific select and specific insert, but not general select and specific insert. I am still puzzled as to what is going on. Any enlightenment would be appreciated